# How do I copy the Release folder contents to a secondary location?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I am brand new to using TeamCity.

I have my .NET C# application building via a MSBuild "build step" in TeamCity.  Once it is built, I would like TeamCity to copy the entire contents of the "Release" folder to a secondary location where we keep current and recent builds.

I cannot build to this location directly because there are other files which my application requires (databases, XML config files, etc..) that reside permanently in the Debug and Release folders.  I know this is horrible and I would need a soapbox to complain about the decisions my predecessor made, but for not I am forced to keep that portion as-is.

Comment: Is it a web application or a "usual" application?

Comment: Have you seen http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin already?

Comment: @D.R. - It is a typical desktop application.

Comment: @D.R. - No I haven't looked into any of the plugins yet.  I am very green when it comes to TeamCity so I hadn't even though of that.

Comment: why can you just write some script/msbuild as another build step to copy it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [command line build step](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Command+Line) with a simple xcopy command.
It will be executed only when every previous build step succeeds.

Comment: That did it!  I guess I should have done some more poking around in TeamCity.  Thanks!